# Unable to provision OpenEBS volume on RancherOS

Tags: openebs, rancheros

I am using Rancher v2 as the k8s management platform and running RancherOS nodes on VMware vSphere.  I manually installed open-iSCSI and mounted a 50GB volumes on the worker nodes for use by OpenEBS (will have to figure out how to automate that on node creation).  I also created a cStor storage class and that all looks good.  However, I have not been able to get a container to provision a pv using a pvc.

```
Warning    FailedMount    Unable to mount volumes for pod "web-test-54d9845456-bc8fc_infra-test(10f856c1-6882-11e9-87a2-0050568eb63d)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "infra-test"/"web-test-54d9845456-bc8fc". list of unmounted volumes=[cstor-vol-01]. list of unattached volumes=[web-test-kube-pvc vol1 man-volmnt-01 cstor-vol-01 default-token-lxffz]
Warning    FailedMount    MountVolume.WaitForAttach failed for volume "pvc-b59c9b5d-6857-11e9-87a2-0050568eb63d" : failed to get any path for iscsi disk, last err seen: iscsi: failed to sendtargets to portal 10.43.48.95:3260 output: iscsiadm: Could not open /run/lock/iscsi: No such file or directory iscsiadm: Could not open /run/lock/iscsi: No such file or directory iscsiadm: Could not open /run/lock/iscsi: No such file or directory iscsiadm: Could not add new discovery record. , err exit status
```

I have followed below steps to enable iSCSI on RancherOS from Prerquisitie section for RancherOS from OpenEBS documentation.

```
sudo ros s up open-iscsi
sudo ros config set rancher.services.user-volumes.volumes [/home:/home,/opt:/opt,/var/lib/kubelet:/var/lib/kubelet,/etc/kubernetes:/etc/kubernetes,/var/openebs]
sudo system-docker rm all-volumes
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

From the github repository of Rancher OS, found that we need to create a lock directory, and make sure to create this directory every boot using the following way

```
$ mkdir /run/lock
# update cloud-config
#cloud-config
runcmd:
- [mkdir, /run/lock]
```

Reference path: github repo of rancher. Then find issue number 2435 under rancher/OS